# send a serializable object over socket

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, remote-server, objectinputstream

I have a strange problem to send a serializable object that I have created over socket. In fact if I run the server and the client in the same machine it works well but if the server and the client are in different machines the readen object in the server side is empty (with size equal to zero)

Any one have an idea to fix that ? (the code is bellow)

Server:

```
public static void main () {
...
InputStream is = mysocket.getInputStream();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);

ArrayList<MyObject> list_of_object;
list_of_object = (ArrayList<MyObject>) ois.readObject();
logger.log(Level.INFO,"object readen with size : "+list_of_object.size());
...
}
```

Client:

```
public static void main () {
...
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(mysocket.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(list_of_object);
...
}
```

Comment: What does that `size()` method in your object do? And what do you mean by "readen object in the server side is empty (with size equal to zero)"? You should more details and explanation.

Comment: My object is an ArrayList so it's the size method of ArrayList objects (returns the number of elements in the list)

Comment: If you are writing/reading `ArrayList` then why are you casting the read object to `MyObject`.

Comment: I have written it this way just for simplicity. MyObject is replaced in my code by : ArrayList<my_serisable_object>

Comment: You've over-simplified to the extent that you've removed the code that shows the problem. Try posting your real code, or at least a cut down version that actually exhibits the problem.

Comment: Ok to be more clear I have modified the code

Comment: If you received an empty list you sent an empty list. This code does not exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following test case with your version of the `MyObject`-class. It will help you to figure out the problem. If this works fine with your class, then it may be the network layer, e.g. you're reading something different than what you expect to read. Common mistakes may be that you're running an old version of your server code somewhere and you may indeed read an empty list of MyObjects.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Test;

public class StreamTest {

public static class MyObject implements Serializable {

}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    ArrayList<MyObject> list_of_object = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    list_of_object.add(new MyObject());
    oos.writeObject(list_of_object);

    byte[] whatGoesOverWire = baos.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(whatGoesOverWire);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
    ArrayList<MyObject> deserialized = (ArrayList<MyObject>) ois
            .readObject();
    assertEquals(1, list_of_object.size());
    assertEquals(1, deserialized.size());
}

}
```